# iOS Soundcloud login problems

Tags: ios, soundcloud

Am attempting to stream my own tracks from my own Soundcloud account. I have the API included in my project and starting the configuration like so:

```
 [SCSoundCloud setClientID:CLIENT_KEY
                    secret:CLIENT_SECRET
               redirectURL:[NSURL URLWithString:REDIRECT_URL]];
```

Am trying to hardcode my own Soundcloud credentials but cannot find a call in SCSoundCloud for this. I don't want to make the user login. Is it necessary to get the user to login to view my tracks or can I provide anonymous access so they can simply stream?

This has been an issue for the last while and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone's interested, it's done using the following:

```
[[SCSoundCloud shared] requestAccessWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];
```

Comment: This won't build in my project, though it's still listed here: http://cocoadocs.org/docsets/CocoaSoundCloudAPI/1.0.2/Classes/SCSoundCloud.html#//api/name/requestAccessWithPreparedAuthorizationURLHandler. Is it deprecated?

Comment: Sorry for taking an absurdly long amount of time to answer this but you have to include the header "SCSoundCloud+Private.h"

Answer (score 0):

Just code it by yourself and do not use the Soundcloud-Wrapper for it, here is a example using AFNetworking for it :

```
        NSMutableDictionary * parameters = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        [parameters setObject:@"password" forKey:@"grant_type"];
        [parameters setObject:self.emailTextField.text forKey:@"username"];
        [parameters setObject:self.passWordTextField.text forKey:@"password"];
        [parameters setObject:CLIENT_ID forKey:@"client_id"];
        [parameters setObject:CLIENT_SECRET forKey:@"client_secret"];

        // Token will not expire 
        [parameters setObject:@"non-expiring" forKey:@"scope"];


        [[SoundCloudClient sharedClient] POST:@"/oauth2/token" parameters:parameters success: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, id responseObject)
         {
             // Store Access-Token
         }

            failure: ^(NSURLSessionDataTask *task, NSError *error)
         {
             // Errorhandling
         }];
```